# VueJS computed data and scopes

Tags: javascript, vuejs2

I'm trying to create an array `elections` as a computed property within my vuejs component, by adding some more UI relevant information to the array `elections` of my datastore.

```
export default {
    computed: {
        data() {
           var elections = [];
           this.$dataStore.state.elections.forEach((el) => {
               console.log(this);
               var election = { id:el.id, icon: 'assignment', iconClass: 'blue white--text', title: el.title, subtitle: 'Jan 20, 2018' };
               this.elections.push(election);
           }); 

           return {
              elections: this.elections
           }
       }
    }
}
```

However, I'm getting a "Cannot read property 'push' of undefined"" error. What is wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Referencing `this.elections` before the `data` method has returned won't work because the Vue instance's data properties haven't been set yet.

But you don't need to reference `this.elections` for what you're trying to do. Just reference the `elections` array that you initialized before the `forEach`.

Also, you have your `data` method in the `computed` object, but it should be outside of it.

Also, as @Bert mentioned in the comments, you probably meant `push` instead of `put` when adding to the array.

Here's what it should look like:

```
export default {
  data() {
    var elections = [];
    this.$dataStore.state.elections.forEach((el) => {
      var election = { id:el.id, icon: 'assignment', iconClass: 'blue white--text', title: el.title, subtitle: 'Jan 20, 2018' };
      elections.push(election);
    }); 

    return {
      elections: elections
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Ahh yeah and it should be `push`, sorry for that!